# REST Get returns some items in a json collection but not all

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx

This is the first time I have encountered a REST API get returning some items in a list inside a collection but not others. Here's an example:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json,odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(productData){
             ... do something ...
    }
});


REST URL: [site url]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Products')/items(6)
```

Returns

```
{
"odata.metadata": "[site url]/_api/$metadata#SP.ListData.ProductsListItems/@Element",
"odata.type": "SP.Data.ProductsListItem",
"odata.id": "7ccff0bc-c97d-4ba3-86e7-a487c251ca6e",
"odata.etag": "\"2\"",
"odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(6)",
"FileSystemObjectType": 0,
"Id": 6,
"ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
"ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
"ContentTypeId": "0x0100C25F3CFD70B42D4DBE5D3FC6E2845A9F",
"Title": "My title",
"Description": "Installation, design, and development of something",
"ProcessId": null,
"Price": null,
"Item_x0020_Type": "Service",
"Category": null,
"VendorItem": null,
"ID": 6,
"Modified": "2017-03-09T19:22:08Z",
"Created": "2016-12-20T20:20:53Z",
"AuthorId": 10,
"EditorId": 10,
"OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
"Attachments": false,
"GUID": "32ce2eb7-8262-43f2-87a2-6e266d787894"
```

}

However:

```
REST URL: [site url]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Products')/items(3)
```

Returns in a collection "d"

```
{
"d": {
    "__metadata": {
        "id": "0b91b075-671f-4774-9e91-948f078fafad",
        "uri": "[site url]/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)",
        "etag": "\"5\"",
        "type": "SP.Data.ProductsListItem"
    },
    "FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "[site url]/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"
        }
    },
    "RoleAssignments": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "[site url]/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/RoleAssignments"
        }
    },
    "Activities": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "[site url]/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/Activities"
        }
    },
    "AttachmentFiles": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/AttachmentFiles"
        }
    },
    "ContentType": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/ContentType"
        }
    },
    "GetDlpPolicyTip": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/GetDlpPolicyTip"
        }
    },
    "FieldValuesAsHtml": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/FieldValuesAsHtml"
        }
    },
    "FieldValuesAsText": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/FieldValuesAsText"
        }
    },
    "FieldValuesForEdit": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/FieldValuesForEdit"
        }
    },
    "File": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/File"
        }
    },
    "Folder": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/Folder"
        }
    },
    "ParentList": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/ParentList"
        }
    },
    "Properties": {
        "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4e866caa-513a-44ea-ba85-c84fff621d5d')/Items(3)/Properties"
        }
    },
    "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
    "Id": 3,
    "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
    "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
    "ContentTypeId": "0x0100C25F3CFD70B42D4DBE5D3FC6E2845A9F",
    "Title": "On-line Store Development",
    "Description": "Installation, design, and development of on-line store",
    "ProcessId": 3,
    "Price": 100.5,
    "Item_x0020_Type": "Service",
    "Category": null,
    "VendorItem": null,
    "ID": 3,
    "Modified": "2017-05-22T17:23:00Z",
    "Created": "2016-12-20T20:20:53Z",
    "AuthorId": 10,
    "EditorId": 10,
    "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
    "Attachments": false,
    "GUID": "65c71feb-e09f-4174-a1c8-3ac69861b7c4"
}
```

}

Why is this happening? And what is the best way to handle this in javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Are these returning same output when you run these from the browser?

Comment: I get the same results as shown above regardless of using a REST utility or my javascript program.

Comment: you have a comma instead of a semi-colon in your content-type header.

Comment: also try eliminating content-type altogether, just accept would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that I may had a discrepancy between my REST Console utility and what my code was actually seeing. All of the items being seen by the code is in a collection "d" with just a single item in it. I discovered the discrepancies after adding the following code and noticing that the "else" was never executed when I stepped through the program!

```
                if (data.d) {
                    var productData = data.d;
                } else {
                    productData = data;
                }
```

I went back to my REST Console utility and noticed that the URL had double / in it!  [site url]**//**_api/web/lists....  What is interesting is that it actually returned a valid object with the correct data in it, just not wrapped in a collection.

Thanks to all who helped!